Glue on skin wudu
As salam alaykum
I have a small wound on my hand and coverd it with a band aid. I changed the band for a smaller one, but i did'nt realise that it left a little bit of glue on my hand with dirt that sticked to it ( i didn't see it nor thought abt it). I don't really remember the amount of glue on my hand ( it was not a big amount but i tend to forget a lot of thing, but just scratching it was enough for it to be gone) nor the number of prayer that I prayed with it on my hand.
Should I repeat prayers, and how ? ( because i don't remmeber the number of salat as i was unaware of this issue ). Should i consider it to be a small amount that let water touch the skin ? It makes me a little bit anxious, because i rode thing on internet but i don't know if water reached my skin.
PS: i  think that i have memory loss, so a few hour later i don't remember  how was the trace left on my hand and i remmeber i used wax today ( but i think it ressembled band aids trace).
thanks !!
